# PHP ZipArchive is zipping the lower directories also

Tags: php, zip

I found this script on stackoverflow but am having an issue. The zip is being created with the file I am telling it to but it's also zipping the lower directories to that file. The zipped file contains: \uploads\1\assets\2\ai\filename.ai

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();

$zip->open('uploads/1/assets/2/ai/filename.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);

$zip->addFile('uploads/1/assets/2/ai/filename.ai');

$zip->close();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$zip->addFile('uploads/1/assets/2/ai/filename.ai', 'filename.ai');
```

The second parameter is the *[localname](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php#refsect1-ziparchive.addfile-parameters)*:

> If supplied, this is the local name inside the ZIP archive that will
>   override the filename.

If you leave off the directory path, it will not be included in the zip file.